# Move and update a marker to a fixed coordinate

Tags: markers, update, leaflet-draw

I used Leaflet and leaflet.draw-src.js with this code : http://bl.ocks.org/TetsuyaKimotsuki/0156c511e3217edf58beb206633308f8

After creating a marker, I want to move it to the coordinates indicated in two inputs : "lat" and "lng"

I added this code

```
function update_position() {
        var latitude =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("lat").value);
        var longitude =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("lng").value);
marker.setLatLng(latitude, longitude).update();
}
```

and a button in the popup

```
var contents = "";
      for (var key in layer.feature.properties) {
        if (key != 'note' && key != 'drawtype') {
          contents = contents + key + " " + layer.feature.properties[key] + "<br />";
      }
      }
contents += "note <input type='text' class='notes' id='note_" + layer._leaflet_id + "' value=''>" "<br />"
+"<button style='width:200px' onclick=\"update_position()\">Update the marker</button><br>";
layer.setPopupContent(contents);
    };
```

While updating I have this error : "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setLatLng') at update_position".

Edit 26/06/2022 :

I found a code in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829195/change-coordinates-of-l-marker-in-l-layergroup , that allowed me to move a marker

I added this code

```
function update_position() {
var id = sessionStorage.getItem('repere');

var lat =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("latdm").value);
var lng =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("lngdm").value);

drawnItems.getLayer(id).setLatLng(new L.LatLng(lat,lng));
```

and a button in the popup

```
var contents = "";
      for (var key in layer.feature.properties) {
        if (key != 'note' && key != 'drawtype') {
          contents = contents + key + " " + layer.feature.properties[key] + "<br />";
      }
      }
contents += "note <input type='text' class='notes' id='note_" + layer._leaflet_id + "' value=''>" 
"<br />"+"<button style='width:200px' onclick=\"update_position()\">Update the marker</button><br>"

sessionStorage.setItem('repere', layer._leaflet_id);

layer.setPopupContent(contents);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a code in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35829195/change-coordinates-of-l-marker-in-l-layergroup , that allowed me to move a marker

I added this code

```
function update_position() {
var id = sessionStorage.getItem('repere');

var lat =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("latdm").value);
var lng =   parseFloat(document.getElementById("lngdm").value);

drawnItems.getLayer(id).setLatLng(new L.LatLng(lat,lng));
```

and a button in the popup

```
var contents = "";
      for (var key in layer.feature.properties) {
        if (key != 'note' && key != 'drawtype') {
          contents = contents + key + " " + layer.feature.properties[key] + "<br />";
      }
      }
contents += "note <input type='text' class='notes' id='note_" + layer._leaflet_id + "' value=''>" 
"<br />"+"<button style='width:200px' onclick=\"update_position()\">Update the marker</button><br>"

sessionStorage.setItem('repere', layer._leaflet_id);

layer.setPopupContent(contents);
};
```